# Avoiding logic in java constructors

Tags: java, oop, constructor, software-design

I've got a class I need to build that takes information from a file and performs certain computations on it. It would be passed a File object and will need to fill in several instance variables (for example, a hash). How can it be done in a way that doesn't put all of the work in the constructor?

One idea I had is to simply pass a single instance variable into the constructor, a File object, and then calculate the required values when necessary. The issue with that though is I need a container for these values, which I will pass to a separate class later down the road. If I implemented this strategy, I'd need a separate class that just contained instance variables.

Comment: Not really an "issue" - I say just go ahead and do it.

Comment: If that logic is really what's involved in building the object, do it. The one exception is I'd say is not to pass a `File` but instead an `InputStream` or `Reader`.

Comment: Why do you want to not do this work in the constructor? A constructor's job is to construct the object, so do whatever you want, as long as the object is safely constructed.

Comment: @PrashantPandey  I was always taught that constructors should only assign variables, not calculate them, or do logic in general.

Comment: @Astrum not really. If the instance creation depends on the constructor, then it makes sense to do it inside a constructor, as long as we make sure that the logic does not cause an exception and the instance of the object under construction does not escape the constructor before it is constructed properly. It also depends on the nature of your application. For an highly responsive application, it might be a bad idea to put long running operations inside your constructor. For background jobs, not so much.

Comment: @Astrum I agree that you should move your constructor logic to a different class. This is a good example of the single responsibility principle. There are good creational design patterns that should work for you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creational_pattern (particularly builder or factory)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly I think you should use Static Factory Method to initialize instance variable or implements logic and then get the class object. Here  will try to implement your problem using static factory method.

```
class SomeClass {
  String hash;
  long size;
  public SomeClass(String hash, long size) {
        this.hash = hash;
        this.size = size;
   }

  public static SomeClass initFromFile(File file) {
     // Implement logics here
     String hashValue = DigestUtils.md5Hex(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file)); // Apache commons
     long fileSize = file.getSize();
     
      return new SomeClass(hashValue, fileSize);
   }
}



Class Main {
    public static void main() {
     File file = getFile();
     SomeClass someClass = SomeCLass.initFromFile(file);
    }
}
```

This is a rough idea how to separate logics from constructor. More about Static Factory Method follow link below.

[Static Factory Methods](https://medium.com/javarevisited/static-factory-methods-an-alternative-to-public-constructors-73cbe8b9fda)

Answer (score 0):

You should not do something in constructor that is likely to fail, in your case there are many things that can go wrong when you are reading the file and you should define your own custom checked exception to notify the user of your API that they are likely to happen when you are building the object. I think there are two approach to solve your problem one of them is to use builder pattern and define logic for building your object there, here is how you can do that:

```
public class Sample {
    private final String name;
    private final String family;

    private Sample(String name, String family) {
        this.name = name;
        this.family = family;
    }

    private static class Builder {
        private String filePath;
        Builder(String filePath) {
            this.filePath = filePath;
        }
        
        public Sample build(File file) throws FileNotFoundException, RequiredInfoNotPresentInFile {
            try(Scanner sc = new Scanner(file)) {
                String name;
                String family;
                if (sc.hasNextLine())
                    name = sc.nextLine();
                else
                    throw new RequiredInfoNotPresentInFile();
                if (sc.hasNextLine())
                    family = sc.nextLine();
                else
                    throw new RequiredInfoNotPresentInFile();
                return new Sample(name, family);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class RequiredInfoNotPresentInFile extends Exception {
}
```

the other way is using static factory method but you should throw your custom Exception to notify user that something bad happen during creation of your object here too:

```
public class Sample {
    private final String name;
    private final String family;

    private Sample(String name, String family) {
        this.name = name;
        this.family = family;
    }

    public Sample fromFile(File file) throws FileNotFoundException, RequiredInfoNotPresentInFile {
        try(Scanner sc = new Scanner(file)) {
            String name;
            String family;
            if (sc.hasNextLine())
                name = sc.nextLine();
            else
                throw new RequiredInfoNotPresentInFile();
            if (sc.hasNextLine())
                family = sc.nextLine();
            else
                throw new RequiredInfoNotPresentInFile();
            sc.close();
            return new Sample(name, family);
        }
    }
}

public class RequiredInfoNotPresentInFile extends Exception {
}
```